# Issue regarding bevel shape and hardened normal shading

Tags: normals, topology, bevel, artifacts

I'm trying to use hardened normal chamfers to make this room more interesting, but I'm having issues with the bevel shape and normals. Cuts keeps appearing in corners or rounded edges like the doorframe.

shading issues on corners:[image: corner artifact]
artifacts and loss of the orginal arc curvature:[image]
complete room (Backface culling is on):[image]
blend file: [image]

How can i fix these shading problems whilst maintaining a relatively low face count? Should i bake a higher poly version to the low poly or is there a better way to approach this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The loss of the original arc curvature as you call it is due to the poor geometry in combination with enabled *Loop Slide* in the *Bevel* modifier, you can see it better with *Harden Normals* disabled. *Loop Slide* guides the bevel along the edges, so disabling it would be better or using different geometry, as you can see in the lower half of the image:

[image: loop slide]

For the shading issues, well these are simply quite large bevels in a single segment  to be smoothened. I would set them at least to 3, or better even 4. As long as you don't apply the *Bevel* modifier, no new faces are generated.

[image: bevel segments]

By the way, there are edges on the floor from one door frame to the other which also have a bevel weight on them. That's not necessary since they are no corner edges that need beveling.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Could you explain to me why my original geometry was problematic so i don't make the same mistake again?

Comment: @João Well, as I wrote in the answer, _Loop Slide_ guides the bevel along the edges (maybe not a professional explanation), which means in your case mostly vertical along those four edges to the side and upwards along the two horizontal edges. There are no edges perpendicular to the arc, following along. I know you want to keep the face count low, so maybe an N-gon would have been better since it doesn't have these guiding edges.

Comment: @João Or maybe you've read somewhere N-gons are bad, avoid them in any case and make quads (which is not always true, sometimes they are even to prefer over quads). But then you should maybe inset the N-gon face like I did in the bottom right example of the first image, and then create quads for the rest of the face. In that case, the bevel would have follow along the arc edges. But as explained in the answer, since you can simply deactivate _Loop Slide_ in the modifier, it won't matter too much.

Comment: I'm afraid that if I ever try to start modeling professionally, meshes made with ngons won't be easily accepted. So I was trying to get better at modeling using only quads (started out using the boolean workflow),even though I know it doesn't matter that much on flat surfaces.

Comment: @João Well, I'm not going to model professionally, so I don't know if you have to always use quads, no matter if they are in some cases making things worse. There are tutorials on Youtube discussing pros and cons of N-gons and quads etc.